# Regex for time format HH:MM AM/am/PM/pm in python

Tags: python, regex

I have written regex to capture HH:MM AM/PM/am/pm but it is not able to extract exact pattern

Code For regex:

```
import re
def replace_entities(example):
    res = ''
 # TIME
    m = re.findall("\d{2}:\d{2} (:?AM|PM|am|pm)", example)
    if m:
        for id in m:
            res = res +"\n{} :TIMESTR".format(id)

    m = re.findall("\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3} (:?AM|PM|am|pm)", example)
    if m:
        for id in m:
            res = res +"\n{} :TIMESTR".format(id)

print(replace_entities('My name is sayli,  Todays time is 12:10 PM Date is 21/08/2018 otal amount is www.amazon.com  chandanpatil@yahoo.com euros 10,2018/13/09  saylijawale@gmail.com. https://imarticus.com   Account number is Accountsortcode:abca123456'))
```

But i am not ale to capture time 12:10 PM as TIMESTR

Link for tried Regex .https://regex101.com/r/Z8lUIW/2
 How do i correct it? any suggestions.please help

Comment: is this all you code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

[`\s(\d{2}\:\d{2}\s?(?:AM|PM|am|pm))`](https://regex101.com/r/UaXJdd/1)

Explanation:

`\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ]) 1st Capturing

`\d{2}` matches a digit (equal to [0-9]) {2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times

`\:` matches the character : literally (case sensitive)

`\d{2}` matches a digit (equal to [0-9]) {2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times

`\s?` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ]) 0 or more times

Non-capturing group `(?:AM|PM|am|pm)` 
1st Alternative `AM AM` matches the characters `AM` literally (case sensitive) 2nd Alternative `PM` 3rd Alternative `am` 4th Alternative `pm`

In action:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\s(\d{2}\:\d{2}\s?(?:AM|PM|am|pm))', 'Time today is 10:30 PM')
['10:30 PM']
```

Comment: Sorry by mistakely it was clicked. The solution have helped me

Comment: Glad to help, happy programming!

Comment: also one question what about if textis  10:30am that is no space between time and am/pm? can you help me for this solution

Comment: Updated my answer to account for that, I made the `\s` in between the time and `AM/PM` optional.

Comment: @chrisz Is there a reason to escape `:`? Doesn't seem necessary.